# Working with zips in pyspark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I have n zips in a directory and I want to extract each one of those and then extract some data out of a file or two lying inside the zips and add it to a graph DB. I have made a sequential python script for this whole thing, but I am stuck at converting it for spark. All of my zips are in a HDFS directory. And, he graph DB is Neo4j. I am yet to learn about connecting spark with neo4j but I am stuck at a more initial step.

I am thinking my code should be along these lines.

```
# Names of all my zips
zip_names = ["a.zip", "b.zip", "c.zip"]

# function extract_&_populate_graphDB() returns 1 after doing all the work.
# This was done so that a closure can be applied to start the spark job.
sc.parallelize(zip_names).map(extract_&_populate_grapDB).reduce(lambda a, b: a+b)
```

What I cant do to test this is how to extract the zips and read the files within. I was able to read the zip by `sc.textFile` but it on running `take(1)` on it, it returned hex data.

So, is it possible to read in a zip and extract the data? Or, should I extract the data before putting it into the HDFS? Or maybe there's some other approach to deal with this?

Comment: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/zip-files.html May be helpful

Answer (score 0):

**Updating Answer***

If you'd like to use Gzip compressed files, there are parameters you can set when you configure your Spark shell or Spark job that allow you to read and write compressed data.

```
--conf spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compress=True \
--conf spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compression.codec=True \ 
--conf spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec \
--conf spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compression.type: BLOCK
```

Add those to the bash script you are currently using to create a shell (e.g. `pyspark`) and you can read and write compressed data.

Unfortunately, there is [no innate support of Zip files](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/zip-files.html), so you'll need to do a bit more legwork to get there.